# Insert a shape in Powerpoint Slide (Office Javascript API)

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, office-js-helpers

Is there a possibility to add a shape (or anything else except for plain text or image) within a PowerPoint slide?

I couldn't find anything on it and really hope it's possible. I already added this request on UserVoice (https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/36881503-insert-shapes-in-powerpoint). Any suggestions?

Comment: Frustrating, I've spent a while getting set up to do this, only to realise that there's practically nothing in the Powerpoint API! Would have been great if I could have rewritten my vb into a neatly packaged addin instead. I've voted your suggestion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality that you've described isn't currently supported by the Office JavaScript APIs in PowerPoint. You've done the right thing by logging this feature request in UserVoice, so that members of the product team can consider it when planning future development of APIs  for PowerPoint.